# Can I automate raspi-config partition resize?

Tags: raspbian, ssh, partition, raspi-config

I understand the process of resizing the disk partition to use the full disk size via raspi-config. Wanted to know a way to automate this process. Here is what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to do a automated installation which:

- Raspbian unattended netinstaller: https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst
- after this finished I'd like a post install script to fire off to enable ssh and resize the partition

Is there a way I can automate this process

Comment: I will need to do more digging but can you not create a bash that fires on boot. Maybe research the Raspbian boot process and add it to the boot script. I shall be back with more goodies.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it probably already does what you want OOTB.

The openssh-server package is installed by default and you can log in with `ssh root@<hostname-or-ipaddress>`. The default hostname is `pi` and default password is `raspbian`.

The standard partitioning is 128MB for `/boot` and the rest of the sd card is for `/` (root).
If you don't want to use the rest of the sd card for root (but less), you can do so by specifying `rootsize=+xM` in `installer-config.txt` where x is the desired size in Megabytes. In a similar fashion you can also have `bootsize=+xM` in `installer-config.txt` to specify the size of the boot partition.

See the [Installer customization section](https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst#installer-customization) for details.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to automate partition expansion to 100% of remaining space with this command:

```
sudo raspi-config nonint do_expand_rootfs
```

You're not done until after a reboot.

```
sudo reboot
```